# Too few parameters error using pyodbc on a query containing a hardcoded where clause?

Tags: sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I've seen several questions about the *"Too Few Parameters"* error but have not found one that quite matches my situation.

Simplified code:

```vb
db.cursor.execute ('''SELECT [PT_NUMBER] FROM [newtest1];''')
```

`newtest1` is a saved MS Access query containing a subquery with a hardcoded `where` clause:

```sql
SELECT table1.PT_NUMBER, table1.ID
FROM table1
WHERE (table1.ID  In (select ID from table2 where field1 = "TESTVALUE"));
```

My error is:

> pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
> Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

If I instead use the same code to select from a query that does not contain a subquery with a hardcoded where clause, I get no error:

```vb
db.cursor.execute ('''SELECT [PT_NUMBER] FROM [newtest2];''')
```

With `newtest2` defined as:

```sql
SELECT table1.PT_NUMBER, table1.ID
FROM table1
WHERE (table1.ID In (select ID from table2));
```

So it doesn't seem to be the most common issue of a column name typo, nor an issue about passing in a parameter directly rather than using `?`, at least not from the code.

It seems that the hardcoded `WHERE` is causing a problem even though it's in the Access query, not the python code.

Is it possible to `SELECT` from an Access query with a subquery with a hardcoded `WHERE` clause in this way, with pyodbc?

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I tried to simplify the problem case from my original situation for the question, and could have sworn that I still got the error, but now I am not getting it with the example I've given.  Where I am actually getting the error, is if the query refers to a *subquery* with a hardcoded where clause.  I've updated the question to show the version of newtest1 that truly produces this error.  I loaded this corrected query into your db file and did still get the error.  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7jsttbwo09ss7f/origtestdb.accdb?dl=0)Here it is. Thank you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with single or double quotes around hard-coded value (and I cannot access Dropbox right now to test what you did). My guess is you may be using [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) in query. Try posting exact SQL query.

Comment: The posted query is exact; the test database consists of only table1 with fields ID and PT_NUMBER, and table2 with fields ID and field1.  The string "TESTVALUE" is the only record in field1 of table2.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue both with Python/pyodbc and with VBScript/ADODB so it's not an issue with pyodbc, it's an issue with the Access ODBC driver. Never seen that one before ....

Comment: Definitely a bug in the Access ODBC driver. Using VBScript/ADODB and the Access OLEDB provider works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  FWIW, Parfait gave me the idea to try single quotes around 'TESTVALUE' in the access query, which I probably should have thought of before, and that produced no error.  More of a workaround than an answer, I suppose.

Comment: Well I'll be darned. TIL. Please consider posting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting this to work correctly, by using single quotes around the hardcoded value in the access query, instead of double quotes:

```
WHERE (table1.ID  In (select ID from table2 where field1 = 'TESTVALUE'))
```

Comment: Same problem here, just replaced the double quotes for the single quotes and it solved. Thanks